# SQL-Server 2008 R2, update Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to update the hosted assembly with a new one? Guessing not. Would like new features found in SqlGeography, like STContains() and not have to write ugly SQL workaround.

//Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I suspect such a change would require a whole lot more than just swapping out a DLL to get the new definition. How would the engine know how to parse never mind process the function? You can't just add FORMAT() or DATETIMEFROMPARTS() to earlier versions by checking in a DLL either.

I think the only way you'll be able to get SqlGeography.STContains() is to upgrade to a version that has it (SQL Server 2012).

Comment: Or write my own

Comment: Sure, you could write your own. But do you really want to? To what end? So you can replace all those references with the native function when you upgrade?

Comment: Of course I will not write my own. And upgrading to SQL2012 is not an option. Will go with the ugly SQL dance.